# Find the polynomial in a linear subspace that minimizes the distance from a given polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

> Consider the inner product space $\mathcal{P}[0,1]$ of all real polynomials on [0,1] with inner product $\langle f,g\rangle =\int_{0}^{1}f(t)g(t)dt$ and $V=\operatorname{span}\{t^2\}$. Let $h(t)\in V$ be such that $\|2t-1-h(t)\|
> \le \|2t-1-x(t)\|$ $\forall x(t) \in V $. Then $h(t)$ is
>
> (a) $\frac{5}{6} t^{2}$
>
> (b)$\frac{5}{3} t^{2}$
>
> (c)$\frac{5}{12} t^{2}$
>
> (d)$\frac{5}{24} t^{2}$

Let $h(t)=\alpha t^2$, $g(\alpha)=\|2t-1-h(t)\|$, Expanding the the expression,
$g(\alpha)=\langle 2t-1-h(t), 2t-1-h(t) \rangle$

$= \int_{0}^{1}(2t-1-\alpha t^3)^2dt$.
Then Extremises $g(\alpha)$.
I got $h(t)=\frac{5}{3} t^{2}$.

Am I correct?

Can I do the problem in different method? Please suggest all the other possible ways.

Comment: Suggestions: try to write a title that describes the problem ("Find polynomial $h(t)$" does not really say what the problem is about).  The correct notation for norm is `\|x\|` and for inner product is `\langle x, y\rangle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the closest point projection of $2t-1$ onto the line $\{ \alpha t^2 : \alpha\in\mathbb{R} \}$. The orthogonal projection and the closest point projection are the same, which determines $\alpha$ by the equation
$$
           \langle 2t-1-\alpha t^2,t^2\rangle =0 \\
        \alpha \langle t^2,t^2\rangle = \langle 2t-1,t^2\rangle \\
           \alpha = \frac{\langle 2t-1,t^2\rangle}{\langle t^2,t^2\rangle}
  = \frac{\int_{0}^{1}(2t-1)t^2dt}{\int_{0}^{1}t^4dt}=\frac{\frac{2}{4}-\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{5}}=\frac{5}{6}.
$$
Looks like answer $(a)$ is correct.

Comment: $\langle x, y\rangle \in \mathbb{R^2}$, projection on the x-axis means it's x- co-ordinate right? but we want the shortest distance from the point to the x-axis. isn't it different notions? please explain.

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan : Whether you're working in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ or in an infinite-dimensional inner-product space, closest point projection onto a subspace is the same as orthogonal projection onto that subspace.

Comment: How to prove that?

Comment: Can you give hint?

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan : Orthogonal projection of $x$ onto a subspace $M$ means $m\in M$ such that $(x-m)\perp M$. Then, for all $m'\in M$, one has $\|x-m'\|^2 = \|x-m+(m-m')\|^2=\|x-m\|^2+\|m-m'\|^2 \ge \|x-m\|^2$, with equality iff $m'=m$. So, the orthogonal projection is the closest-point projection.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan : You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably made a slight calculation error but you're on the right track. You should find that
$$
\int_0^1 (2t-1 - \alpha t^2)^2 dt = \frac{1}{15} \left( 3\alpha^2 - 5\alpha+5\right)
$$
Minimising this should give you $\alpha = \frac{5}{6}$.

You can also easily find the answer if you take the projection of $f(t) =2t-1$ onto $V$. This projection is given by
$$
Pf = \frac{\langle f,g \rangle}{\langle g,g \rangle} g
$$
where $g(t) = t^2$. Notice that for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
\| f-Pf \|^2 = \| (f-\alpha g) - (Pf- \alpha g)\|^2= \|f-\alpha g\|^2 - 2 \langle f - \alpha g, Pf - \alpha g \rangle  + \|Pf- \alpha g \|^2 \\
= \| f-\alpha g \|^2 - \left( \frac{ \langle f, g \rangle}{\langle g , g \rangle} - \alpha \right)^2 \langle g,g \rangle.
$$
So clearly $\| f-Pf \|  \leq \| f - \alpha g \|$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Then all that is left to do is calculate $$
\frac{\langle f, g \rangle}{\langle g, g \rangle}
$$
which is indeed $\frac{5}{6}$ as we found earlier.