# distance between the point $z = (0,0,1,0)$ to the plane $\Pi$ that passes through the point $x_{0} = (1,0,0,0) $?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

I was trying to find the distance between the point $z = (0,0,1,0)$ to the plane $\Pi$ that passes through the point $x_{0} = (1,0,0,0) $ and is parallel to the vectors $v_{1} = (1,-1,1,-1)$ and $v_{2} = (0,2,2,0)$.

It is done using the Gram-Schmidt procedure in the solutions, but there are some steps in the middle that I do not understand.

For example, the solution defines  $\Pi_{0} = \operatorname{Span}(v_{1},v_{2})$
and says $\Pi = \Pi_{0} + x_{0}$, I dont see how? Seems like a translation of the plane?

Also, in the next step, it says that the distance between the point $z$ and the plane $\Pi$ is  same as the distance between the point $z-x_{0}$ and the plane $\Pi_{0}$?

And in the last step, it applies the Gram-Schmidt procedure to the vectors $v_{1},v_{2},z-x_{0}$, yielding orthonormal vectors $(w_{1},w_{2},w_{3})$?

And the required distance is $|w_{3}|$.

I see this involves a bit of visualization or technicality, any help in understnding the above points is nice!

Answer (score 2):

$\Pi_0=Span(v_1, v_2)$ represent the plane parallel to vectors $v_1,v_2$ but it passes through origin. To make it contain the point $x_0$ you add $x_0$ to $\Pi_0$.

Similarly the distance between $z$ and $x_0$ is same as the distance between $z-x_0$ and origin if we shift the origin to $x_0$.

Not really sure about the last doubt.

Comment: How you deduced that $\Pi_{0}$ pasees through origin, cant get that quickly?

Comment: The span of $v_1,v_2$ means all vectors of form  $k_1v_1+k_2v_2$ where $k_1,k_2$ are real. If both are 0 then it vector is 0 and hence the plane passes through origin

Answer (score 2):

The first step is indeed a translation so that the plane passes through the origin. This is a rigid motion, so doesn’t affect distances between objects.

The distance from a point to a flat (line, plane &c) is measured in a direction orthogonal to the flat, so is the length of the *orthogonal rejection* of the point from the flat, i.e., the remainder after subtracting the orthogonal projection onto the flat. This is precisely what the Gram-Schmidt process computes at each step: the orthogonal rejection of a vector from the span of the basis vectors computed up to that point.

Answer (score 1):

**Attempt 1:**

$\Pi=\{(1,0,0,0)+xv_1+yv_2|x,y \in \mathbb R\}$.
We can to find the distance from $(0,0,1,0)\to \Pi$.
Let $p \in \Pi$. $p=(1,0,0,0)+x(1,-1,1,-1)+y(0,2,2,0)$. Distance from  $(0,0,1,0)\to \Pi$, let denoted by $D$.

$$D^2=(x+1)^2+(-x+2y)^2+(x+2y-1)^2+x^2.$$ Problem turn in to minimize $D^2$.

**Attempt 2:**
$$
           \langle z-x_0-xv_1-yv_2,x_0-v_1\rangle =0 \tag{1}$$

$$\langle z-x_0-xv_1-yv_2,x_0-v_2\rangle =0 \tag{2}$$
 Solve for $x,y$.

[Find the polynomial in a linear subspace that minimizes the distance from a given polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493876/find-the-polynomial-in-a-linear-subspace-that-minimizes-the-distance-from-a-give/2494014#comment5152773_2494014).
This link may help you.

Comment: why $\Pi=\{(1,0,0,0)+xv_1+yv_2|x,y \in \mathbb R\}$ ? Actually its right but how to deduce that? Yes this is also another method to do! but I was using Gram Schmidt process!

Comment: $\Pi=\{(1,0,0,0)+xv_1+yv_2|x,y \in \mathbb R\}$. since $\Pi_{0} $  is the spans of $v_1$ and $v_2$. $x_0$ can not be the point inside the $\Pi_{0}$. Right? three vectors are LI. plane passing through $x_0$ will be the translation of $\Pi_{0}$. by $x_0$. Am I correct?

Comment: Plane passing through $x_0$  and parallel to $\Pi_0$ will be a translation of $\Pi_0$ by $x_0$.